# Define attributes in method parameters in F#

Tags: f#

I'm doing a DLL import in F# and then passing some parameters for a method.

```
 [<DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)>]
        extern bool OpenPrinter([<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>] szPrinter)
```

`A parameter with attributes must also receive a name` is the compilers answer.

This method must have a MarshalAs attribute before it, like we have in C#

```
[DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter);
```

The parameter of OpenPrinter is a `string` called `szPrinter`, but it have an attribute `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr])`

F# doesn't accept this like C#.
How to define attributes inside method parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your extern function is expecting a type for the parameter:

```
extern bool OpenPrinter([<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>] string szPrinter)
```